# How to manage file up-loading when files have same name?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I am creating a Web Application Java EE and Jsp. I have created a file upload program using apache fileupload. IT works well. But i have a real world problem.

That is , suppose let us imagine 2 users of my site uploading a file with same name as `Emp_docu.doc`. But both have different content. The uploaded files are saved in `\uploads` directory.

Now my question is:

If multiple users uploads the file with same name, is all files with same name will rewrited and only single files exist? For example, in the above said, not two `emp_docu.doc` will saved in folder `\uploads`, only single `emp_docu.doc` exists and any one users uploaded will lost.

What is the solution for it without degrading server performance?

(even though we can rename the file, is it possible to rename the uploaded file before it saved in server directory `\uploads`).

Answer (score 1):

I always append unique ids before the file names if the directory is same.

For eg. for user id 12 the file would be `12_Emp_docu.doc`, and user id 15 the file would be `15_Emp_docu.doc`.

Comment: ok. then what happens if same user uploads a file with same name twice(that is in two different days).

Answer (score 0):

while I like the above [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12663693/1634475) a lot better, this might also work for you:

What if you created an upload folder for each user such as

```
user1/uploads/Emp_docu.doc
```

OR

What if you created a folder for each user inside uploads such as

```
uploads/user1/Emp_docu.doc
```

Comment: Ok. But creating lot of folders (consider my site have 54,567 users !! then 54,567 folders will created ..) will degrade HDD performence. It is true?